# How do I remove "Customer" data type from the below - a generic EF delete machine

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, expression-trees

I've managed to code myself into a corner. I'm trying to build code that given a `TableReference` object containing a EFTable name and a PrimaryKey name, is able to delete all the records in my RemovedRecords collection below.

I've managed to build the simple case where the records are all for a "Customer", but they will not all be.

How do I go about geting the code to use the "classToQuery" datatype instead of the customer below?

```
// remove all given records for this table
foreach (IPoco record in serverResult.RemovedRecords[tableReference]) // will loop for each record to delete from the given tablereference
{
    // first query EntityFramework and get the list of all Customers
    object currentRecords = efTable.GetValue(entities); // will return entities.Customers

    // get the class "Customer"
    Type classToQuery = efTable.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0]; // will return typeof(Customer)

    // get the value of the primary key as an expression
    var primaryKeyValueOfRecord = Expression.Property(Expression.Parameter(classToQuery),  tableReference.PrimaryKeyPropertyName); // will return customer.customerId 

    // get the actual constant id to compare with
    var primaryKeyValueToFind = Expression.Constant(record.DictionaryRepresentation[tableReference.PrimaryKeyPropertyName]); // will return 3654

    // get the comparison as a lambda function
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Customer, bool>>(Expression.Equal(primaryKeyValueOfRecord, primaryKeyValueToFind)); // will return x=>x.CustomerId = 5654

    // go find the record in EF that we should delete
    object recordToRemove = ((IQueryable<Customer>)currentRecords).Where(lambda); // will return { Name: "Joe", CustomerId: 3654 }

    // Remove the record from EF
    currentRecords.GetType().GetMethod("Remove")?.Invoke(currentRecords, new[] { recordToRemove });  // will remove Joe(3654) from the db
}
```

Comment: What is your db? why not make a stored procedure that can delete records without pulling them back from the db first? you seem to overcomplicate the stuff a lot, or I am just missing a lot from your use case

Comment: Essentially I'm receiving a data feed of table names and primary key fields to delete, then I need to tell entityframework to do it.. I *could* implement it with a massive case statement, and that is currently the route i'm going, but it would have been nice if i could tell ef, find the table with name "customer", find the record with "customerid" equal to 6, and nuke it

Comment: I *could* also create a stored procedure, as you suggest. It's a fun thought exercise anyway

Comment: Or just execute direct SQL, it doesn't sound like this functionality would need a lot of refactoring in the future, so I wouldn't mind clear text SQL. You can get the table name and the column name from the mappings.